# build-helper-maven-plugin causing AnnotationTypeMismatchException

Tags: java, maven, annotations, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to generate a schema from a java class. The schema, in turn, is referenced by a WSDL document. so for instance, I have a **common-ws-data project**. The **common-ws-data** project contains a "**FaultMessage**" object; which looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "FaultMessage",namespace="urn:ws.mycorp.com:common:faults", propOrder = {"message"})
public class FaultMessage {

@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
protected String message;

/**
 * @return the message
 */
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

/**
 * @param message the message to set
 */
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

this generates a schema through JAXB; and the resulting schema looks like this:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" targetNamespace="urn:ws.mycorp.com:common:faults" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="FaultMessage">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

So far so good. However, we want to version our schemas and WSDLs, and various best practice suggestions around the web suggest embedding the versioning info into your namespace. So...

```
urn:com.mycorp.ws:common:faults
```

would become

```
urn:com.mycorp.ws:common:faults:1.3.1
```

Obviously, this means modifying the annotation to

```
 @XmlType(name = "FaultMessage",namespace="urn:ws.mycorp.com:common:faults:1.3.1", propOrder = {"message"})
```

However, since the schema project can get quite large, it's impractical to have to update the annotations on ALL of your domain objects each time your version changes. So the idea I had was to somehow pull version information from the maven POM file and concatenate this value onto the default namespace.

To that end, I wrote my own maven plugin which will create a "**ProjectConstants**" class which exposes various maven project attributes as public final String fields; i.e.:

```
public final class ProjectConstants {

public static final String ARTIFACT_ID="common-ws-data";
public static final String GROUP_ID="com.mycorp";
public static final String VERSION="1.3.1";

}
```

The annotation can now become:

```
@XmlType(name = "FaultMessage",namespace="urn:ws.mycorp.com:common:faults:" + ProjectConstants.VERSION, propOrder = {"message"})
```

This works fine if the generated ProjectConstants class is placed in the same source path as the FaultMessage java file (i.e. **src/main/java**)

However, IF I have my plugin generate the **ProjectConstants** class in a different source path; for example: **/target/generated/maven**; and then add the generated source folder as an extra source folder via the **builder-helper-maven-plugin**, the maven compilation process blows up with an **AnnotationTypeMismatchException**.

Here is the maven configuration for the builder-helper-maven-plugin. Pretty standard, basically:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>target/generated/maven</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Here is the exception we get:

```
Problem encountered during annotation processing; 
see stacktrace below for more information.
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: Incorrectly typed data found for    annotation element public abstract java.lang.String    javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType.namespace() (Found data of type java.lang.String)
at com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.declaration.AnnotationProxyMaker$ValueVisitor$1.generateException(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:241)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:56)
at $Proxy3.namespace(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.XmlTypeQuick.namespace(XmlTypeQuick.java:36)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeInfoImpl.parseTypeName(TypeInfoImpl.java:152)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:169)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.createClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:339)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:239)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:330)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.j2s.JavaCompilerImpl.bind(JavaCompilerImpl.java:90)
at com.sun.tools.jxc.apt.SchemaGenerator$1.process(SchemaGenerator.java:115)
at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessors.java:60)
at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Apt.java:454)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:258)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1102)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:964)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:95)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:85)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.tools.jxc.AptBasedTask$InternalAptAdapter.execute(AptBasedTask.java:97)
at com.sun.tools.jxc.AptBasedTask.compile(AptBasedTask.java:144)
at com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2.SchemaGenAdapter.execute(SchemaGenAdapter.java:111)
at com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2.SchemaGenMojo.execute(SchemaGenMojo.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR

I suspect it's some kind of class-loader problem... the type of the **namespace()** attribute of the **@XmlType** annotation IS java.lang.String; and obviously the concatenation of "**urn:com.mycorp.ws:common:faults**" and **ProjectConstants.VERSION** is a string as well; so it should work, in principle; and it definitely works if I put **ProjectConstants** in **/src/main/java**. So I suspect what's happening is that **builder-helper-maven-plugin** is somehow modifying the classpath AFTER **/src/main/java** has already been read; which then triggers the AnnotationTypeMismatchException.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You use com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2:maven-jaxb-plugin why you just don't tweak execution order to make compilation of your interfaces and then run jaxb compiler and then compile you final code.

There's one easier way : just move your interface to another jar (artifact) and make your dependent on it. So that compilation order will be natural.

Have fun.